# Headphone jack broke and trying to force the speakers

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, speakers, microphone

My headphones jack is broken inside of my laptop. I need to replace it but can't now. I used to listen from my computer from both headphones and speakers, but I opened up my laptop today and I couldn't hear anything again...

My cousin yesterday put my phone headphones into the microphone place in my laptop and I am wondering if its from that.

Can someone suggest temporary solution to hear from my laptop?

[image: http://prntscr.com/bhwxtb]

[image: http://prntscr.com/bhwy3o]

Comment: Under Playback right-click on "Communication Headphones" and then choose "Disable Device" , This will disable the use of headphones and re-force the Windows to play the sounds from the speakers.

Comment: Is there a configuration utility for your audio? Depending on the hardware, sometimes these have an option to play 'phones and speakers together, and enabling this should be a temporary solution. I have just seen @iSR5's comment, which similarly depends on the hardware, specifically, whether plugging in the lack plug causes a physical disconnection in the speaker circuitry.

Comment: @iSR5 i tried your suggestion, it didn't work.

Comment: @AFH i don't have one of those that you are mentioning.

Comment: That's unusual: there is usually a Realtek or similar utility, with a separate icon in the system tray, but it may be hidden as inactive.

Comment: I don't know what to do. I am still trying to solve it, I tried lots of posts that had similar issues but couldn't get it to work. whats weird is that yesterday it worked fine. i had speakers and headphones active. but today when i started my laptop i couldn't hear anything again.

Comment: @Munkiuke It may be from the IDT sound control panel, and it might be installed on your system. Recheck that, and try to use it to disable the headphone jack.